# Remove notification on clicking (Not a duplicate)

Tags: android, notifications, foreground-service

Please don't mark this as duplicate without reading the question fully as many similar questions are there.

My question is exactly as the title says :
I have used a foreground service to display a static notification.i want to remove the notification when user clicks the notification.
i know I must be missing something in my code  :

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Truiton Music Player")
                .setTicker("Truiton Music Player")
                .setContentText("My Music")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous,
                        "Previous", ppreviousIntent)
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play, "Play",
                        pplayIntent)
//              .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "Next",
                        pnextIntent).build();
//              notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        startForeground(100, notification);
```

The commented lines are the ones I tried but no luck in those.

Comment: @duggu Please read the question before marking it as duplicate

Comment: just make stopForeground by starting BroadcastReceiver which will startService with a command which will call stopForeground.